# Pass multiple data field from <select multiple> to Django formfield via JQuery .val()

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, multi-select

I have an application where I have many instances of passing individual html selected user selections to a form field with no problem, but I am struggling to do the same in a multiselect case. It seems that the `JQuery.val()` function is creating a proper array of data but my formfield on the server shows an empty string. I inherited this application and am somewhat of a noob at this.

The relevant javascript function is

```
$('.exemptionfield').change(function() {
    var exemptionfield = $(this)

    $.ajax({
        url: '/form/ASubstanceExemption',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            sclId: $('#sclId').val(),
            substance: exemptionfield.attr('id'),
            exemption: exemptionfield.val()
        }
    })
})
```

The form looks like

```
class ASubstanceExemption(forms.Form):
   buttonTitle = 'submit'
   title = 'not used'

   sclId = forms.IntegerField()
   substance = forms.CharField()
   exemption = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False,
                            choices=kExemptions)
   def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
      sclId = self.cleaned_data['sclId']
      substance = self.cleaned_data['substance']
      exemption = self.cleaned_data['exemption']
      print exemption
etc...
```

The HTML select looks like

```
<select multiple size="5" class="exemptionfield" id="Lead/lead compounds">
<option value="1(a)">
    1(a)
</option>
<option value="1(b)">
    1(b)
</option>
<option value="1(c)">
    1(c)
</option>
<option value="1(d)">
    1(d)
</option>
etc....
```

In cases where I have a single select html drop down and a single choice `form.ChoiceField`, a selected value (of the type of `exemptionfield`) will be passed to the exemption variable in my form. Never had a problem there. If I switch to the `form.MultipleChoiceField` and select a single variable to be passed as in `exemptionfield.val()[0]` for example, this also works fine. It will come through in the format of (example) `[u'1(b)']`. But the moment I remove the `[0]` and only use `exemptionfield.val()` then it seems like I only receive an empty array in my form. My print action only shows `[]` as a result. But looking at the values sent by the javascript using an alert function, it tells me it is sending `1(b)`,`1(c)`,`1(d)`.

Any hints where I am going wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using ?

Answer (score 5):

I *think* you're having the same problem I just solved. You just have to change a setting in jQuery (new as of v1.4, as per [this discussion](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-post-1-4-1-is-appending-to-vars-when-posting-from-array-within-array), and referenced in the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)), so that it doesn't append square brackets to the serialized variable sent in the POST data.

When I sent `my-form-field = $('#my-multi-select').val()` with `.post()`, it was sending it as:

```
my-form-field[] = 4
my-form-field[] = 7
```

Trying to reference this as form.cleaned_data['my-form-field[]'] instead of form.cleaned_data['my-form-field'] didn't work, Django only looks for the form field name without the brackets.

Anyway, adding this line:

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```

...will make it send the data as

```
my-form-field = 4
my-form-field = 7
```

From what I gather in the discussion linked above, the default behavior works better in PHP and Rails, but causes this problem with Django. Maybe Django should adapt?